# Removing Glance from watchOS

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-3

I am trying to upgrade my watchOS 2 app to watchOS 3, since it uses the Glance, I remove the swift code and also the Glance UI from storyboard.

But I still got this error when launch on device, what else should I removed?

Error Launching "xxx"
Glances aren't supported on this version of watchOS.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the error message, switch from Glance to others in Scheme (Info tab).